# AssetManager loads sound too slow on android

Tags: java, android, libgdx, assets

I want to load the 'bang.ogg' file from my assets folder using the LibGDX AssetManager:

```
am.load("bang.ogg", Sound.class);
am.finishLoading();
```

On my Xiaomi Redmi 4X it takes 2 minutes to load this 42Kb-sound! Apk size is 2Mb.

I load an image. But it loads in mills:

```
am.load("test.jpg", Texture.class);
```

What I have to do? What causes this problem?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and consider updating your question.

Comment: have you tried with other `.ogg` file ?

Comment: Yes I do. The same problem. But loading time still depends on the file size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the [Sound](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/audio/Music.html) implementation is that it will load the entire file into memory. According to the wiki you should not use it on Android [if the file size exceeds 1MB](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Sound-effects):

> **note**: On Android, a Sound instance can not be over 1mb in size. If you have a bigger file, use Music

Your audio is smaller than 1MB but using the [Music](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/audio/Music.html) implementation allows you to stream the audio so it will not get loaded on startup but [streamed while playing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Streaming-music):

> For any sound that's longer than a few seconds it is preferable to stream it from disk instead of fully loading it into RAM. Libgdx provides a Music interface that lets you do that.

I would give that one a try.

Comment: But what can cause this problem? Music is loaded in a few milliseconds!

Comment: [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/9b8f20b2d0e96e53f0f2b98dc8f6131c810aae71/backends/gdx-backend-lwjgl/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/audio/Ogg.java) is the implementation of both, Audio and Music for Ogg sounds. In order to debug the slow part, create this class in your project in the correct package `com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.audio` and use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to measure how long each part takes. It will give you an indication what the problem might be.

Comment: Ok, I will try.